# Getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of the button text to "white" whenever I click the button. But after clicking the button,I get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined".I tried to extract the object by using console.log(this) but it does not return the object of button which I clicked,rather it returns an object of type "window".I cannot understand why I am unable to access the button and select the text inside it and change the color.I am pasting my html and js code.Please let me know where  am going wrong.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < (document.querySelectorAll('.drum').length); i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

    this.style.color = "white";

  });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #283149;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: "Arvo", cursive;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DA0463;
}

footer {
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.w {
  background-image: url(./images/tom1.png);
}

.a {
  background-image: url(./images/tom2.png);
}

.s {
  background-image: url(./images/tom3.png);
}

.d {
  background-image: url(./images/tom4.png);
}

.j {
  background-image: url(./images/snare.png);
}

.k {
  background-image: url(./images/crash.png);
}

.l {
  background-image: url(./images/kick.png);
}

.set {
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.drum {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no code shown that tries to set a `color` property, and therefore this code is not a good [mre]. Please show code that, when run, reproduces the error you are asking about. Do note that you're better off caching the response to `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")` in a variable, then iterating over that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey try to run the snippet..it works and the issue will be reproduced

Comment: I ran the snippet and do not see the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined".

Comment: @HereticMonkey ohh yes!! I saw I did not save my changes which I did and so it just showed undefined..please see now it shows the error!!

Comment: `.color.style` should be `.style.color`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting `undefined` is because you are using arrow function, and `this` is referring to the `window`. The solution is to use `event.target` in place of `this`.

You can achieve the same by using anonymous function, in place of arrow function, and use `this` in that.

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  all[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    event.target.style.color = "#fff";
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #283149;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: "Arvo", cursive;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DA0463;
}

footer {
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.w {
  background-image: url(./images/tom1.png);
}

.a {
  background-image: url(./images/tom2.png);
}

.s {
  background-image: url(./images/tom3.png);
}

.d {
  background-image: url(./images/tom4.png);
}

.j {
  background-image: url(./images/snare.png);
}

.k {
  background-image: url(./images/crash.png);
}

.l {
  background-image: url(./images/kick.png);
}

.set {
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.drum {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button class="w drum">w</button>
  <button class="a drum">a</button>
  <button class="s drum">s</button>
  <button class="d drum">d</button>
  <button class="j drum">j</button>
  <button class="k drum">k</button>
  <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please at least add a few lines of explanation. Code only answer are not really useful.

Comment: @johannchopin I was editing the answer for explanation.

Comment: Better now I removed the downvote ;) Please first finish a little bit your answer before posting next time :)

Comment: Will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use an arrow function which don't bind `this`, see the [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_arrow_function.asp):

> With arrow functions the this keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function.

Just use an usual `function() {}` if you want to bind the `this`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < (document.querySelectorAll('.drum').length); i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    console.log(this.innerHTML);

  });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #283149;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: "Arvo", cursive;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DA0463;
}

footer {
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.w {
  background-image: url(./images/tom1.png);
}

.a {
  background-image: url(./images/tom2.png);
}

.s {
  background-image: url(./images/tom3.png);
}

.d {
  background-image: url(./images/tom4.png);
}

.j {
  background-image: url(./images/snare.png);
}

.k {
  background-image: url(./images/crash.png);
}

.l {
  background-image: url(./images/kick.png);
}

.set {
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.drum {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a common error; one which has been answered many times before...

Comment: Thanks will keep this in mind!!